# other meanings of the word "appetite"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-usage

I was having an interview yesterday and I was talking about people's tastes when it comes to food. The interviewer asked me a question about whether young people and old people in my city like the same kinds of food, and I said, "young people have different appetites for food than older generations." is it okay to use "appetites" in this context? I thought it would give the same meaning of "preferences"!!

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: [You were being interviewed?] Anyway, appetite for food is the main way it is used....appetite for other things (sex, drugs and rock n' roll, for example] would be other appetites.

Comment: Because ***for food*** is in fact the ***default*** sense of "appetite", it's not normally explicitly specified when that's the intended meaning. By somewhat non-idiomatically including it in your text, you're encouraging your readers to think of some slightly *different* sense that you might be trying to convey (maybe you're talking about young people's ***cerebral*** relationship to their diet, as opposed to the ***visceral*** relationship to whatever they're eating or salivating in anticipation of).